# One-form on the $\mathbb Z$ covering

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

Let $X$ be a closed manifold and $\tilde X$ be its $\mathbb Z$-covering, what I know is that any function $f\in C^\infty(\tilde X)$ does not descend to  $X$ in general sense.

**Q**: Why $df$ is the pull-back from $X$ of  a closed one-form? Does this also  hold for any closed One-form?

Comment: Are you thinking about a particular example? I don't think this is true in general, since for example $x dx = .5  d(x^2)$ on $\mathbb{R}$ is not the pullback of a $1$ form from $S^1$, since it is not periodic. (On the other hand, the $\mathbb{Z}$ invariant forms and functions are pullbacks.)

Comment: @AreaMan It is a good example, I just saw this on taubes's paper, gauge theory on aymptotically periodic  a manifold, page373.

Comment: What is the $\mathbb{Z}$-covering of a manifold?

Comment: @AmitaiYuval The fiber of each  point in $X$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z$ and $\mathbb Z$ actions as translate on $\tilde X$.

Comment: So, for example, what is the $\mathbb{Z}$-covering of a genus 2 closed Riemann surface?

Comment: Alternatively, what is the $\mathbb{Z}$-covering of the 2-sphere?

Comment: But then the fiber is a singleton. I don't get it. It seems that only very specific manifolds have a $\mathbb{Z}$-covering.

Comment: @AmitaiYuval Sorry, in your case there is no $\mathbb Z$-covering, but let assume the $\mathbb Z$-covering exists .